# List of equipment you can parry with in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

New to the soulsborne series, only played a little Bloodborne and just started Dark Souls 3. What is a list of equipment you can parry with? I assume the parrying mechanic is similar to gunshots in Bloodborne.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [wiki](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Parry) has the full list of equipment that allows you to parry.

These are mostly shields, and any dual weapon, but the parry mechanic only works with the left hand. Any shield that has the Parry skill is indicated by this icon - a small circular icon in the bottom corner:

[image]

The only exceptions to this rule are the Parrying dagger, The Farron  Greatsword, and most Katanas.

- The Farron Gratsword is a Dual weapon, that is accompanied by a dagger. With the Dagger equipped, you can use the Parry ability.
- Most Katanas have a "hold" skill, which has the Parry ability.
- The Parrying Dagger has a skill that allows you to Parry in either hand.

There are also a few shields that don't let you parry, since they have a different "skill" attached to them, but some shields have no skill, they simply allow you to use the skill of the weapon in your right hand, without having to two-hand it first.

[image]

Comment: Also, similarly to fist weapons, you can parry with your left hand when you are empty handed (ie: no weapon equipped in each hand).